# Read part of shapefile specified by a bounding box

Tags: c++, gis, shapefile, gdal, ogr

I am looking to read part of a `shapefile` for an area specified by an image's bounding box using `GDAL` and `C++`. I think the `GDAL` program `ogr2ogr` has this feature using the [clipsrc flag](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) but I am unsure how to call it from within a program or if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: You can use the new layer algebra in 1.10 to make an intersect, this is more or less equivelent to the clipsrc. It modifies the geometry. To get geometries in a region without modifying them use the SetSpatialFilter() method.